# How to create List View builder item like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter. Please guide me how can i add a button at the last index of listview builder. I don't understand how can i attach the button at the last position.

[image]

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class ListCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListCheckState createState() => _ListCheckState();
}

class _ListCheckState extends State<ListCheck> {
  
  
  List<Color> colors=[Colors.black,Colors.green,Colors.yellow,Colors.red,Colors.blueGrey,
    Colors.deepPurple,Colors.cyan,Colors.purple,Colors.orange,Colors.pink];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: colors.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,item){
            return Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class ListCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListCheckState createState() => _ListCheckState();
}

class _ListCheckState extends State<ListCheck> {
  
  
  List<Color> colors=[Colors.black,Colors.green,Colors.yellow,Colors.red,Colors.blueGrey,
    Colors.deepPurple,Colors.cyan,Colors.purple,Colors.orange,Colors.pink];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: colors.length+1,
          itemBuilder: (context,item){
if (colors.length== item) {
return Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),),
                ),
              ),
            ) }
            return Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use that, I hope it fix your problem